# Where clause in LINQ Query with Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am trying to filter a LINQ query, but it's not accepting my where clause and I have no idea what kind of Lambda function to use.

This is what I want, but this throws an error.

```
var query = from s in _db.Students where s.Payments == null orderby s.LastName select s;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Payments` is not a field of `Students`, but rather a property representing a collection of `Payment` items related to this `Student`, try this query instead:

```
var query = from s in _db.Students where !s.Payments.Any() orderby s.LastName select s;
```